# Find the sum of the series $3x+8x^2+15x^3 + ....$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to express the following series $3x+8x^2+15x^3 + ....$ as a sum and hope to find its sum for $|x| < 1$

Here is what I have so far:

To me the series looks to be the derivative of the following form:

$1 + \frac{3}{2}x^2+\frac{8}{3}x^3+\frac{15}{4}x^4 ...$

Given that the denominator progresses as $\frac{1}{n}$ I had thought of taking it out like so:

$\frac{1}{n}(1+3x^2+8x^3+15x^4 ....)$

Now I'm unsure of the sequence that the constants follow but lets denote this as $a$ and take it out of the sequence of $x$ values, then I get:

$\frac{1}{n}(1+a(x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5 ...))$

We know that the sum of the series of $x$ follows the following geometric series: $\frac{x^2}{(1-x)}$, plugging this into the equation:

$\frac{1}{n}(1+\frac{ax^2}{1-x})$

Then taking the first derivative I get:

$\frac{ax(2+x)}{n(1-x)^2}$

I'm unsure as to whether the $n$ can still be introduced or whether it's removed - How is this answer optimally derived?

Following the hint below:

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(n^2-1)x^n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(n^2-1)x^n =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^2x^n - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n = \frac{x(1+x)}{(1-x)^3}-\frac{x}{1-x}$$?

Comment: I'm not sure how we're supposed to be able to tell what's beyond the $\cdots$.  Without a general formula for the coefficients, it could be anything.  Is there some sense in which you know what all of the coefficients are?

Comment: Why did you add $1$?

Comment: @Henry Because when we take the derivative we get back to the original equation, and I would need $\frac{1}{1}$ when $n=1$ to fulfill the series of $\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: That makes it more complicated and prone to mistakes; similarly your $\frac1n$. You might do better to start with $\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots$ and manipulate it with differentiation and other steps to get to $3x+8x^2+15x^3+\cdots$

Comment: @Henry I think that you're right as when I look back at it I should have split the summand for both the geometric series and the $\frac{1}{n}$. Although without knowledge of the coefficients I'm pretty much set-up to fail. This was a valuable lesson on series for me!

Comment: These questions all have the inherent problem in that given any finite sequence, you can come up with a rule to fit them that has anything you want as the next term through polynomial interpolation.  So it's only a "fair" question if the rule is bloody obvious or given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check your $\frac{x(1+x)}{(1-x)^3}-\frac{x}{1-x}$ you will find it is $3x^2+8x^3+15x^4 + \cdots$ so you need to remove a factor of $x$ to get  $\frac{(1+x)}{(1-x)^3}-\frac{1}{1-x}$ though I would not write it that way

If you know the coefficient of $x^n$ is $n(n+2)$ then one approach could be to manipulate $\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots$ and say

- $\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+\cdots$
- $\frac d{dx} \frac{1}{1-x}=1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+5x^4+\cdots$
- $x \frac d{dx} \frac{1}{1-x}=x+2x^2+3x^3+4x^4+5x^5+\cdots$
- $\frac d{dx}\left(x \frac d{dx} \frac{1}{1-x}\right)=1+ 4x+9x^2+16x^3+25x^4+\cdots$
- $\frac d{dx}\left(x \frac d{dx} \frac{1}{1-x}\right) -\frac{1}{1-x} = 3x+8x^2+15x^3+24x^4+\cdots$

which seems to be what you want.

You can then find $$\frac d{dx}\left(x \frac d{dx} \frac{1}{1-x}\right) -\frac{1}{1-x} = \frac{2 x}{{{\left( 1-x\right) }^{3}}}+\frac{1}{{{\left( 1-x\right) }^{2}}}-\frac{1}{1-x}= \frac{x(3-x)}{(1-x)^3}$$

Comment: I think the $\frac{x}{1-x}$ was an edit from someone else.Now that I look at my notes $1+x+x^2+x ... = \frac{1}{1-x}$ so if $n=1$ then the smallest value $x^n$ takes is $x$ hence the first is what I should have put.

Comment: This approach fits better with my understanding from my lecture notes! +1

Answer (score 3):

Hint $1$: First notice that the coefficients are $n^2-1$.

Hint $2$:
\begin{eqnarray*}
 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  n^2 x^n  =\frac{x(1+x)}{(1-x)^3}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: If indexing from $1$, the coefficients are actually $n^2 + 2n = (n+1)^2-1$.

Comment: Can you check my answer as I'm unsure whether I've been thrown off by the summation index